# How can I change the property of my css attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following css code :

```
input:checked + .selectablelabel .check {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And I would like to modify using javascript the property of the attribute visibility and to set to visible using javascript.

I tried this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#selectlabelall', function () {
document.getElementsByClassName("input:checked + .selectablelabel .check").visibility = "visible";
});
```

But without any effects.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: `"input:checked + .selectablelabel .check"` isn't a classname. Consider [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Not to mention you'll need to iterate through them; you can't modify all of them using `.visibility`.

Comment: Also, you're mixing jQuery and non-jQuery here. If you're going to import and use jQuery, use it for all of your selectors.

Comment: I tried this : `I tried this $(document).on('click', '#selectlabelall', function () { var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".selectablelabel.check"); for(container of containers) { container.style.visibility = "visible"; } });` but it does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

Hey the way you are using is incorrect!
Use this instead :

```
  $(document).on('click', '#selectlabelall', function () {
  let elements = 
 document.getElementsByClassName("input:checked + 
 .selectablelabel .check");

 for(element of elements) {}
      element.style.visibility ="visible":
  }
  );
```

Comment: I tried this `$(document).on('click', '#selectlabelall', function () {
  var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".selectablelabel.check");
  for(container of containers) {
      container.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
});` but it does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#selectlabelall', function () {
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("selectablelabel check")
    var i = 0;
    while(i < ele.length) {
        ele[i].style.visibility = 'hidden'
        i++
    }
});
```

Adding the `style` attribute should solve your problem. Also try using the jQuery way to select the element since you are already using the library

Comment: The answer still works! The above code needs to have the style tag with the JS selector

Comment: I've removed my comment (and downvote) as it was incorrect. That said, I would advise against combining jQuery and vanilla JS selectors.

Comment: Yes i agree, And i have mentioned that with he answer, As it would be the best practice.

Comment: I tried this `$(document).on('click', '#selectlabelall', function () { var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".selectablelabel.check"); for(container of containers) { container.style.visibility = "visible"; } });` but it does not work :/

Comment: @EddieBetton I have edited my code to make it work. Kindly check now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your intent is for the full functionality, but here are my assumptions for your specs:

1. hide the label of any checked checkbox
2. show label of any unchecked checkbox
3. if, the "selectall" checkbox is checked, you should show the labels of the other checkboxes regardless of whether they are checked or not

If that's all true above, then you could handle all this in CSS:

```css
input:checked + .selectablelabel .check {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#selectlabelall:checked ~ .selectablelabel .check {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="selectlabelall">



<input type="checkbox">

<label class="selectablelabel">
  <span class="check">one</span>
</label>


<input type="checkbox">

<label class="selectablelabel">
  <span class="check">two</span>
</label>


<input type="checkbox">

<label class="selectablelabel">
  <span class="check">three</span>
</label>
```